# tokenizing a comma separated list using std regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &str) {
  std::regex rgx("");  //what goes here??
  std::smatch base_match;
  std::regex_search(str, base_match, rgx);
  return {base_match.begin(), base_match.end()};
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,
                         const std::vector<std::string> &strs) {
  for (const auto &str : strs) {
    os << "-> " << str << "\n";
  }
  return os;
}

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
  std::cout << split("asdasd,dasdasd,adadada");
  return 0;
}
```

I want to have a regex solution (without using the sregex_token_iterator or boost) that gives sub-matches for a comma separated list and skips the commas (and spaces after/before commas too).

```
expected output:
asdasd
dasdasd
adadada
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with, say, repeated application of `str.find(',')` and `str.substr`?

Comment: So you want regex that will read in a space separated list or a comma separated list or a combination of space and comma separated list?

Comment: @NathanOliver i want it to handle stuff like that  {a, b,c ,d}

Comment: @Chowlett I know there are other ways to do this I just want to know how (if possible) to do it with regex because I saw alot of solutions that use the sregex_token_iterator so there is probably a regex solution without it

Comment: Are you expecting to escape commas within the list items?

Comment: I want the sub-matches to have no commas or spaces

Answer (score 1):

So you want a regular expression that matches a comma (`,`) surrounded by any amount (`*`) of white-space (`\s`)?

It's trivially constructed: `\s*,\s*`

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info